# Can't use public enum in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have this code:

```
import Alamofire

extension Alamofire.Request {
public func responseObject<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(completionHandler:(NSURLRequest?,NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
let responseSerializer = GenericResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data in

guard let responseData = data else {

    let failureReason = "Object could not be serialized because input data was nil."
    let error = Error.errorWithCode( .DataserializableFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
    //Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

    return .Failure(data, error)

}}}
```

The `.DataserializableFailed` is defined in Alamofire:

```
public struct Error {
public enum Code: Int {
    case InputStreamReadFailed           = -6000
    case OutputStreamWriteFailed         = -6001
    case ContentTypeValidationFailed     = -6002
    case StatusCodeValidationFailed      = -6003
    case DataSerializationFailed         = -6004
    case StringSerializationFailed       = -6005
    case JSONSerializationFailed         = -6006
    case PropertyListSerializationFailed = -6007
}
}
```

If I put `Code` before `.DataserializableFailed` it will say: Use of unresolved identifier 'Code'

What's wrong?

Comment: @Rob problem solved, thank you!

Comment: But I wonder why there's still bug when I put `.Code` before `.DataSerializationFailed`

Comment: You can either refer to the fully qualified value `Error.Code.DataSerializationFailed`, or if the type `Error.Code` can be inferred (as it can here), you can use the "dot syntax" and just reference the enum value, e.g., `.DataSerializationFailed`. While it may have been graceful if the compiler could have inferred what you meant by `.Code.DataSerializationFailed`, it's not altogether unsurprising that it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your capitalization/spelling is different. It should be `.DataSerializationFailed`, not `.DataserializableFailed`.

Or you could refer to `Error.Code.DataSerializationFailed`.